# Espresso: how to find child by type in layout?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have ListView without id inside RelativeLayout. 
Could you please tell me how to find it using android espresso test framework and than click on item with specific text ?

Answer (score 3):

As you may already know, Espresso supports Hamcrest matchers, which you have already with Android testing support library.

Here you would find a reference to that: [Hamcrest 1.3 Quick Reference](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf) with all available matchers.

Moreover, every view may have at least one of these elements `id`, `text`, `content description` and so in many situations you can use `withId`, `withText`, `withContentDescription` matchers.

I don't know  why your `LinearLayout` don't has an `id`, I think it' really good practice to add idis for all your views, no matter if you don't use them nowadays.

If your `ListView` don't have any of that elements, but its parent `RelativeLayout` has you can write code like this:

```
onView(withParent(withId(R.id.relative_layout))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

If I am wrong and `RelativeLayout` also doesn't have any of this element look for his sibling, his descendant like `TextView`, which would be grandson to `LinearLayout` or find its forefather.

If you've already found it, use one of this Hamcrest matchers: `withChild()`, `withParent()`, `hasSibling()`, `hasDescendant()`

Your code would look like this:

```
    onView(withChild(withChild(withId(R.id.action_bar_main))))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed));
```

Hope it help

Comment: thanks a lot! Your answer really helped me. P. S. ListView I need to use in my test is from third-party library. It creates dynamically and  does not have id attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Code works for me:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(allOf(withParent(withId(R.id.slider_layout)), instanceOf(ListView.class))).atPosition(drawerPosition).perform(click());
```